# CSS show all children

Tags: html, css, menu

I wonder if is possible to only use css for 'when hover, show all children' ??

I created a example

> http://jsfiddle.net/fantill/SEhX5/4/

Now have 3 level of `li`, and when hover `li` will show next level of `li`.

I want when hover first level `li` then all next level of `li` will show up.

Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: I cannot see some {position:fixed}-elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nav ul > li:hover * {display:block}
```